# Arabic sin and shin sounds in Classical times

Tags: phonetics, phonology, sound-change, arabic

What sounds did س and ش‎ make in (early) Classical Arabic?

I have heard that maybe they were not [s] and [ʃ]. Is that a widely accepted truth? If that's true, what is the evidence for that?

Comment: The history of Semitic sibilants seems to be unclear in general, according to this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Semitic_language#Fricatives

Comment: for what it's worth, you can find fairly detailed descriptions of pronunciation in very early writings (al-Khalil, Sibawayhi) and when I read them I came away with the definite impression that Arabic Sheen was definitely not the same as English /sh/.  Maybe close to German ch in "Ich"?  Sorry I cannot point you to specific passages but it's in there. http://beta.sibawayhi.org